# VSCode "files.exclude" not working for specific targets

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

In my workspace settings file I have

```json
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js": {
            "when": "$(basename).ts"
        },
        "app/**/*.js.map": {
            "when": "$(basename).ts"
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried `app/**/*.map` and `$(basename).js` and it doesn't work. How can I exclude .map files from being shown when I'm using TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the $(basename) evaluates to "app/**/*.js" (with the asterisks expanded), only excluding the ".map" part, not ".js.map" as you might expect.

Try using "when": "$(basename)" for your .map files - that will work like "exclude .js.map files when a .js file exists."

Comment: Oh, I have tried that before, only I didn't know it mapped to the `js` file instead. Thanks.